# PHPStorm : automatic upload on all content roots

Tags: ftp, mapping, phpstorm, sftp

I'm new to PHPStorm and I would like to do something I was used to with the plugin SFTP in Sublime Text : Map different remote hosts to the folders I added in my project and enable automatic upload for all of them.

When you enable automatic upload in PHPStorm, it asks for you to define a default remote host. It looks logical not to allow automatic upload for all folders in case one of them would be mapped to several remote hosts (which one should I choose... ?). But I wondered if it is possible when you assign only one remote host per folder to enable auto-upload for all of them.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible, please follow [WI-5134](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5134) for updates